# DAX formula for previous month's values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to DAX. In order to get the previous month's sales, I have used DATESBETWEEN and passed MAX(Date)-1 as the start date and as the end date EOMONTH.

I got the correct results. However, what are the other simpler ways of getting the same?

```
CALCULATE (
SUM ( AW_Sales[Sales Amount] ),
DATESBETWEEN (
    AW_Calender_Lookup[Date],
    DATE ( YEAR ( MAX ( AW_Calender_Lookup[Date] ) ), MONTH ( MAX ( AW_Calender_Lookup[Date] ) ) - 1, 01 ),
    EOMONTH (
        DATE ( YEAR ( MAX ( AW_Calender_Lookup[Date] ) ), MONTH ( MAX ( AW_Calender_Lookup[Date] ) ) - 1, 01 ),
        0
    )
)
```

)

update - based on an answer given I added a new measure, but the value is empty. [image: As you can see Number 1 from the bottom detailed matrix is placed on the summary matrix at the top, so as number 2, but number 3 (done using previous month) doesn't produce a total and empty in summary matrix]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a **Dates** table which is basically a calendar table, there is a simple way. Your data/fact table has to be connected to the **Dates** table using the date column for say **date**. Now you can create your Date slicer from the **Dates** table. For say, you selected the month September-2020 from the slicer, this below measure will return the SUM for current month-

```
total_sales = SUM(table_name[sales])
```

And this below measure will return the total sales for previous month-

```
total_sales_previous_month = 
CALCULATE(
    [total_sales], 
    PREVIOUSMONTH('Dates'[date])
)
```

For more information on DAX function PREVIOUSMONTH, you can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/previousmonth-function-dax).